# How do I tell Modelsim to not create a wlf file when I carry out simulation?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

The wlf file contains the wave dump data. For some reason I get this message on my computer:

```
#           File in use by: leader  Hostname: DESKTOP-LEADER7  ProcessID: 14602
# 
#           Attempting to use alternate WLF file "./wlftnzmqtm".
# ** Warning: (vsim-WLF-5001) Could not open WLF file: vsim.wlf
# 
#           Using alternate file: ./wlftnzmqtm
```

Why it can't open the file I do not know. Basically I have commands to compile all files and then invoke vsim. I just invoke these .do files and soon I start seeing this error. I just want Modelsim to stop creating wlf files as I do not need them and because of this error, Modelsim ends up creating a lot of wlf files.

Comment: A workaround for suppressing the generation of the wlf file is to use the -novopt option in vsim, `vsim -novopt <design>`. If you need to generate a wlf file with a specific name, use `vsim -novopt -wlf <wave_file> <design>`.

Comment: novopt has to do with optimization right? How is that linked to the wlf file?

Comment: Yes. novopt is to turn off optimizations. However, I have seen that it also suppresses the wlf generation. When using novopt, you will have to use the wlf option specifically in order to generate the wave file. This may not be a solution for your problem, but will allow you to continue your simulations without the error.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when ModelSim has crashed or otherwise not been exited correctly.

Exiting correctly means using the Windows menu Close option or the window's corner 'X' icon. Incorrectly is by a program crash, a Windows crash, using a 'process kill' etc.

Here, your ModelSim launches and finds an existing vsim.wlf, causing  it to create a pseudo-randomly-named alternative .wlf file to use instead. Had the earlier ModelSim session been exited correctly, it would have happily re-used the existing vsim.wlf file. There's clearly some tidying-away actions it carries it during program exit that makes a vsim.wlf re-usable to itself.

In any event, you can resolve the situation by closing ModelSim correctly and manually deleting the vsim.wlf files plus any others it has created. The next time you launch ModelSim, it will create a new vsim.wlf that it can re-use each session.